# Still receiving the same ipn message after response back to paypal

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

According to paypal ipn documentation, I need to response back to paypal once received an ipn message. The problem is I am still receiving the same ipn messages even after I got an "VERIFIED" from the paypal server. Is there anything wrong with what I did? I am using responseBackIpnMessage to response back ipn message. And I always receives a "VERIFIED".

```
 public void handlePaypalIpnMessage(HttpServletRequest request) {
            Map<String, String> configMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            IPNMessage message = new IPNMessage(request, configMap);
            boolean isIpnVerified = responseBackIpnMessage(request);
            Map<String, String> map = message.getIpnMap();
            ......
        }

private boolean responseBackIpnMessage(HttpServletRequest request) {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
    HttpParams clientParams = httpClient.getParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(clientParams, 40000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(clientParams, 40000);

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(paypalIpnUrl); // https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
    httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    try {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cmd", "_notify-validate"));
        Enumeration<String> names = request.getParameterNames();
        while (names.hasMoreElements()) {
            String param = names.nextElement();
            String value = request.getParameter(param);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(param, value));
            params.put(param, value);
        }
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        if (!verifyIpnResponse(httpClient.execute(httppost))) {
            logger.error("Previous message is invalid according to paypal server.");
            return false;
        } else {
            logger.info("Previous message is verified by paypal server");
            return true;
        }
    } catch ( UnsupportedEncodingException e ) {            
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch ( ClientProtocolException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch ( IOException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;    
}

private boolean verifyIpnResponse(HttpResponse response) throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
    InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String responseText = reader.readLine();
    is.close();
    logger.debug("Paypal server ipn response: " + responseText);
    return responseText.equals("VERIFIED");
}
```

Comment: The problem is I didn't response 200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting repeat IPNs that means your script is failing one way or another and is not returning a 200 OK response back to PayPal's server.

The verification process really doesn't have anything to do with that.  That simply verifies the data came from PayPal.  It doesn't verify the script completed successfully.

If you follow the steps in this guide on [how to test PayPal IPN](https://www.angelleye.com/test-paypal-ipn/) you should be able to find the problem.